# Bootstrap based ecommerce theme is not integrating correctly in angular8 project?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

i have `bootstrap` based ecommerce theme with all necessary files. `Html` theme is loading perfectly.

Here is the link of official theme page which i am integrating in `angular8` project.

[Theme page link](http://demo.posthemes.com/pos_juvento/layout2/en/)

I have created `angular8` project repo on github that have updated code of my project. You can clone it and run it on your own machine to check what's the issues are there in my project due to which my theme page is not appearing correctly in `angular8` project

Here is the url of github repop

[RepoLink](https://github.com/fahadsubzwari924/angular-sevvep)

Comment: For Angular is better to use @angular/material then bootstrap. XD

Comment: To add a general css, simple add in your angular.json, in the tag "styles", before "styles.css", "theme-babd1244.css"

Comment: @Mises , why do you say that is better use @angular/material? If you want use angular material you need it, but it's not necesary. Angular is NOT angular+ angular/material

Comment: @Eliseo Tell that to Bootstrap team explain them that Angular is Single Page Application and some of their interact tools are not working.

Comment: I agree with you that use jQuery and Angular together it's a bad idea, but you can use anothers tools like ng-bootstrap. About the question, I understood that there are a problem loading .css

Comment: did you all over-viewed my github repo of project to see the problem that exactly what problems are there in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Theme should work on some not Single Page Application framework. I think there is a problem with bootstrap because of `.js` libraries for interact with user. It's better to use `@angular/material` in Angular projects.

Comment: `bootstrap` is working fine but `slider css` and `slider js` and some other `js` files seems like not working. Bootstrap is working fine.

Comment: Yeah i know bootstrap.css will work but not `.js` files associated with it.

Comment: so what's the solution now? i already have purchased a bootstrap based theme which i have to integrate in my angular project. And slider js is not working actually and that slider js is not associated with bootstrap. and some other js are also not working. Please clone my github repo and run the app to see the issues.

Comment: If You really need that theme You need to just save css files and rebuild all interactions by your code. It will be quite hard to do. XD Check may be some of interactions will work.In other hand could be faster to build theme by your own in Angular application together with dedicated tools to it. Best solution will be to not use Angular but other framework. You should use theme dedicated to Angular if you want to use Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Angular material based on `Bootstrap` here is the link of it

```
https://material.angular.io/
```

Or else you can use the Angular Kendo UI components for the project , it provides very wider range for it for the UI controls , here is the link for it

```
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I mentioned that i have `bootstrap` based whole theme which i bought from a vendor and now i am implementing that theme into my `angular8` project so in implementing that there are some issues. Please see my github repo just clone it and run it to see issues.